# How to prove that $\omega \wedge d \omega =0 $ here?

Tags: differential-geometry

This question is from my exercise in Differential geometry and I am struck on it. So, I am posting it here in hope of getting some help.

> Let $\omega$ be a differential $1-$ form on a manifold $M$ and consider a nowhere - vanishing function $f: M \to \mathbb{R} $ such that $d(fw)=0.$ Prove that $\omega \wedge d\omega =0.$

Attempt: we have $d(f\omega)= df\wedge \omega + f d \omega $ and $f(x)\neq 0 $ for all $x\in M$ , we have $d\omega = (-1/f) df \wedge \omega $. As $\omega$ is a differential 1-form , we have $ \omega \wedge d\omega = -(1/f) \omega \wedge df \wedge \omega$ , but I am not able to move forward from this.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done. Since

$$ \omega \wedge d\omega = -(1/f) \omega \wedge df \wedge \omega = (1/f)df \wedge  \omega \wedge \omega$$

and $\omega$ is a one form, hence $\omega\wedge \omega = 0$.